# AngularJS $on не ловит событие

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

Здравствуйте, пытался понять один вопрос который у меня возник с $broadcast в AngulaJS, но так ничего не понял. Мое приложение работает, но хочется докопаться до истины.
**Собственно вопрос:**
Почему данный код не работает?

```
app.controller('AuthController', function ($scope, $rootScope, DeviceService){
      $rootScope.$on('device_info:ready', function(){
        console.log("It's OK");
    });
});

(function () {
    app.service('DeviceService', function ($rootScope) {
      function init() {
        if(true){
          $rootScope.$broadcast('device_info:ready');
        }
      }
      init();
  });
})();
```

А этот работает:

```
app.controller('AuthController', function ($scope, $rootScope, ServiceTest){
    $rootScope.$on('device_info:ready', function(){
        console.log("It's OK");
    });
    ServiceTest.test();
});

app.service('ServiceTest', function($rootScope){
  this.test = function(){
    if(true){
      $rootScope.$broadcast('device_info:ready');
    }
  };
});
```

- **Можно ли что-то сделать с первым примером чтобы он заработал?**
- **Объясните пожалуйста почему первый не работает а второй работает**(я примерно понимаю, что я "слушаю" событие до того как оно
  происходит?)

Comment: так как сервис не используется, он вполне может быть не инстанциированным, следовательно его функия не выполнялась, и функция init, которая находится внутри, соответственно тоже. Проверить это можно просто добавлением логов, чтобы убедиться, что он даже не заходит в конструктор.

Comment: Добавил логи, в первом случае ф-ция выполняется ДО контроллера, во втором случае ПОСЛЕ. Получается в первом случае слушатель на событие еще не был инициализирован, соответственно поймать его он не может.
И все же не могу понять почему событие в первом случае не "доживает" до выполнения кода контроллера?

Comment: Service инициализируется раньше контроллера. В момент передачи сервиса в контроллер, сервис УЖЕ создан. Следовательно, в первом случае функция ``init()`` вызывается на этапе создания сервиса и ДО создания контроллера. Во втором случае, функция ``test`` вызывается в самом контроллере.

Comment: Получается $broadcast(из DeviceService)  не "живет" до того момента как создается контроллер?

Comment: Он же не бессмертный. ``broadcast`` "запускает" событие. Все кто подписан на него отрабатывают и всё. Событие уходит в цифровой рай.

Answer (score 0):

Сервис объявите вот так:

```
app.service('DeviceService', function ($rootScope) {
  return function () {
      function init() {
          if(true){
              $rootScope.$broadcast('device_info:ready');
          }
      }
      init();
  }
});
```

В этом случае результатом создания сервиса будет функция, внутри, которой, вы уже можете объявить все свои свойства и т.д.

Comment: такой код ломает все зависимости от этого сервиса в моем приложении.

Comment: Мне сложно судить о зависимостях в вашем коде, не видя ни кода, ни логики работы вашего приложения.